# c code: error in the syntax of structs and their fields

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors, field

So i wrote the following code.

```
NameOfStruct *S;
if (statement) {
    S = (S)->property[10];
}
```

I defined the structure beforehand. So the error i am getting is this:

'*S' is a pointer; did you mean to use '->'? and then the line where i typed the code. I find this weird since they ask me if i meant -> while that is exactly what i use. If i instead use the following code

```
S = (*S)->property[10]
```

then i get that that there is a wrong assignment with an incompatible pointer type.
What is happening here?

Comment: Don't hide pointers behind a `typedef`.

Comment: What is `NameOfStruct`? What is `property`? You are not showing enough code. We need a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Your question is kind of hard to understand, but I think I understood enough to help you.

I think your problem might be in the way you defined the struct, and not on the code that uses it.
Firstly, I don't know what `NameOfStruct`is, so i'll define one in this example:

```c
typedef struct test {
    int someValue;
    char someString[10];
}EXAMPLE;
```

What this does is define a struct. You can either call for `struct test` or `EXAMPLE` when you want to do something with that struct.

Now, when it comes to use that struct, you can only use `->` when you are dealing with  pointers. Also, when using Structs, you should allocate memory using `malloc()`.

In your main, you should have something like this:

```c
int main () {
    //Declare pointer to struct and allocate memory.
    EXAMPLE *test = (EXAMPLE*) malloc(sizeof(EXAMPLE));
    
    //Manipulate data on struct
    test->someValue = 10;
    test->someString = "Testing";
    free(test);
}
```

This way, you should be left with a struct where on `someValue` the content is `10`and on `someString` the content is `Testing`

Also, if in your main  you don't feel like using `EXAMPLE` you can also just use `struct test`. Don't forget to free the memory you allocated when you don't need it anymore.

PS: Please, next time you ask a question be sure to give a good explanation on what the problem is, show us what your attempt was, and give us the input/output you were expecting paired with the input/output that you got. If you're left with any questions, feel free to reply to this answer and I'll try to help you